# Can't solve enum related display options in booking service

Tags: c#, enums

I've got a booking service in which you can select by an enum if you want to display all seats, all available seats or all booked seats.

My problem is that I don't know how to make it so i.e. only the booked seats are shown, because as of now if I select "only booked seats" it shows the correct number of reserved seats, but it iterates from the beginning of the entire array instead of the ones that I want, so if there are 3 reserved seats, it will show seat 0,1,2 instead of the ones that are actually reserved.

I am pretty sure that I need to change the `for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfSeats; i++)` instead to actually loop through all seats instead of just as many as there are of the kind that I want to display, but then I get out of bound exception and I don't know how to proceed.

```
public string[] GetSeatInfoStrings(DisplayOptions choice)
    {
        int count = GetNumOfSeats(choice);

        if (count <= 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        string[] strSeatInfoStrings = new string[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            strSeatInfoStrings[i] = GetSeatInfoAt(i);
        }
        return strSeatInfoStrings; 
    }


public string GetSeatInfoAt(int index)
    {
        int row = GetRow(index);
        int col = GetCol(index);

        string seatInfo;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetName(m_nameMatrix[row, col])))
        {
            seatInfo = MarkAsVacant(row, col);
        }
        else
        {
            seatInfo = MarkAsReserved(row, col);
        }
        return seatInfo;
    }
```

I've got a method IsReserved(int index) and tried something like this

```
if (IsReserved(i))
            {
                // Want to return all seats that are reserved
            }
            else if (!IsReserved(i))
            {
                // Want to return all seats that are NOT reserved
            }
```

As far as for that method working, it is okay, but the problem is that I don't know what to put within the brackets.

Comment: Its impossible to answer Erik, only you know what should go inside. Its dependent on your apps logic. How do you get all seats that are reserved just from one seat that's related to `i` variable? I think you should loop entirely first, add seats to a list, and then return the collection after the loop, which is what you see in the two answers below. I think you're not explaining your problem very clearly.

Comment: @nawfal Indeed, I sincerely apologize for being so diffuse. I've been stuck with this for a while and as you can see I'm having trouble describing it, but I think both of you are onto something.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question where we cant help without knowing your complete model. There is little detail. May be you want something like this:

```
string[] strSeatInfoStrings = new string[count];
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfSeats; i++)
{
    var seatInfo = GetSeatInfoAt(i);
    if (seatInfo  == "reserved") //some kind of checking
    {   
        strSeatInfoStrings[counter] = seatInfo;
        counter++; //run another counter
    }
}
return strSeatInfoStrings;
```

You can avoid all the hassle of array and counter and just use a `List<T>`..

```
var strSeatInfoStrings = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfSeats; i++)
{
    var seatInfo = GetSeatInfoAt(i);
    if (seatInfo  == "reserved") //some kind of checking
        strSeatInfoStrings.Add(seatInfo);
}
return strSeatInfoStrings;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @nawfal. I will edit and put up some more and hopefully clarifying.

Comment: @Erik as an optimization, you can check if `count` variable is zero and directly return without even entering the loop, but do ensure to return an empty collection rather than null..

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to use a List than an array in this case, because with a List you don't need to know the size before you start adding to it.

```
public string[] GetSeatInfoStrings(DisplayOptions choice)
    {
        List<string> lstSeatInfoStrings = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfSeats; i++)
        {
            string seatInfo = GetSeatInfoAt(i);

            if (seatInfo.Reserved)
            {
                lstSeatInfoStrings.Add(seatInfo);
            }

        }
        if (lstSeatInfoStrings.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return lstSeatInfoStrings.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: good advice @nawfal but I was just preserving the behaviour of the function.

Comment: Good advice @PollyShaw, thank you. But do I need to have one list for each enum (potential display choice)? Or can I somehow overwrite it?

Comment: `lstSeatInfoStrings` is local to the method, so no you dont need to maintain separate lists foreach enum. Just pass the enum, and get the collection returned back. Once the method is exited, you lose the scope, and when you call `GetSeatInfoStrings` method another time, its a new list in memory that will be created, different from the earlier one. You dont have to bother about that anyhow.